# Keep Top n% of Data Over Time

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a graph with cumulative goals scored by every NHL player over time:

[image]

As you can see, there are far too many players on the current graph. I want to keep only the top (let's say) 10% of the data, but looking back to prior years. For example, if a player is NOT in the top 10% in 1995 but WILL BE in the top 10% by 2000, I want to keep all observations for that player.

Here's what I tried:

```
playerID <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
year <- c(2002,2000,2000,2003,2001,2001,2000,2002,2002,2001,2003,2003)
goals <- c(25,21,27,31,39,34,42,44,46,59,55,53)
my_data <- data.frame(playerID, year, goals)

cumulative_data <- my_data %>%
  group_by(playerID) %>%
  arrange(playerID, year) %>%
  mutate(cumsum_goals=cumsum(goals))

ggplot(data=subset(cumulative_data, percent_rank(cumsum_goals) > .90), aes(x=year, y=cumsum_goals, group=playerID)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Total Goals")
```

But this gives only the top 10% of data overall rather than top 10% by year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your 10% can be interpreted in 2 ways: players who make the top 10% of any given year or players who make the top 10% of the cumulative goals up to that year. I take from your usage of `by` (in `WILL BE in the top 10% by 2000`) and your use of `cumsum()` that you meant the later.*

For better illustration, I changed your cutoff value to `40%` (otherwise none of your players are selected) and the `goals` data (your values are so close from each other that it is very hard to have only some of the players selected. Your values were also ordered, with players making more goals per year over time, which could confuse the interpretation of what is being ordered in the result).

```
library(tidyverse)

# Your data
playerID <- rep(1:3, 4)
year <- c(2002, 2000, 2000, 2003, 2001, 2001, 2000, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2003, 2003)
goals <- c(0, 55, 34, 0, 39, 27, 5, 44, 46, 0, 21, 40) # I changed some values
my_data <- data.frame(playerID, year, goals)

# Create a vector of unique seasons to pass to purrr::map()
seasons <- unique(my_data$year)

# Create a function which selects players above the cutoff for any given season
# (taking into account all seasons up to that one)
select_player <- function(season) {
  total_goals <- my_data %>%
    filter(year <= season) %>%
    summarise(sum(goals)) %>%
    simplify()
  my_data %>%
    filter(year <= season) %>%
    group_by(playerID) %>%
    summarise(rank = sum(goals) / total_goals) %>%
    filter(rank >= 0.4) %>% # change this to 0.9 if you want a 10% cutoff
    select(playerID) %>%
    simplify()
}

# Pass your seasons vector and your function to purrr::map()
# to get the result for all years in a vectorized fashion 
# (equivalent of a for loop but in a functional programming framework).
# And select unique values of the result to combine all years.
# This is your list of selected playerIDs.
selection <- unique(as_vector(map(seasons, select_player)))

# Create a data frame with your selection and the cumsums to plot
my_data_select <- 
  my_data %>%
  filter(playerID %in% selection) %>%
  arrange(playerID, year) %>%
  group_by(playerID) %>% 
  mutate(cumsum_goals = cumsum(goals))

# Plot your selection
ggplot(my_data_select, aes(x = year, y = cumsum_goals, group = playerID)) +
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Total Goals")
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to worry about the final total for each player, i.e. the sum, when picking the top 10%. You can calculate that in a separate table and then use it to filter the data for the plot:

```
top_players = my_data %>%
    group_by(playerID) %>%
    summarize(total_goals = sum(goals)) %>%
    # Cutoff of 0.9 won't work in the example dataset so have changed
    #  it to 0.5, change back to 0.9 for full dataset
    mutate(top10 = percent_rank(total_goals) > 0.5) %>%
    filter(top10)

ggplot(cumulative_data %>% filter(playerID %in% top_players$playerID),
       aes(x=year, y=cumsum_goals, group=playerID)) +
    geom_line() +
    xlab("Year") +
    ylab("Total Goals")
```

Comment: Thinking about this again, it may be that you want to do something slightly more complicated, where anyone who is in the top 10% of total goals *up to that point in time* is kept - that would require a fairly different approach.